# Combine a two-step Insert/Select into one?

Tags: mysql, insert-into

I have an Insert into Table/Select from Table query that group/group_concats on specific values and then a second step

where I do the same from the second table into a third to get my final value and am wondering if I can do this all

somehow in one step.

A **simple version** of my query

```
Insert into Table2 (O,D,M,Zs,TotalPercent)
Select O,D,M,group_concat(Z),Sum(Percent) 
from Table1
Group By O,D,M

Insert into Table3(O,M,Ds,Zs)
Select O,group_concat(D),group_concat(Zs)
from Table2
Group by 0,M
```

Is there a way to do this in a single insert query into Table3?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can in this way

```
  Insert into Table3(O,M,Ds,Zs)
  Select O,group_concat(D),group_concat(Zs)
  from (Select O,D,M,group_concat(Z),Sum(Percent) 
        from Table1 
        Group By O,D,M) as table 2
  Group by 0,M
```